# Is it possible to except figures in the Appendix from being repositioned by endfloat?

Tags: endfloat, appendix

Currently the floats in my appendix are repositioned to the end of the document as well. Is there a way to except them from endfloat?

Comment: If you run \processdelayedfloats, everything after is normal (IIRC).  Another possibility would be to create a new environment.  This will require some experiments.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am running `\processdelayedfloats` before the appendix but it still moves my appendix floats to the back and creates a second list of figures etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This both uses `\processdelayedfloats` and creates a new environment.  (It will work without `\processdelayedfloats`, but the figure counter will get messed up.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nodelay}[1][tp]{\@float{figure}[#1]}{\end@float}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text 1

\begin{figure}
  \caption{endfloat test}
\end{figure}

text2

\processdelayedfloats

\begin{nodelay}[h]
  \caption{nodelay test}
\end{nodelay}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `endfloat` package uses a macro called `\efloat@restorefloats` to restore the old definitions of all environments it has re-defined.

So using `\csname efloat@restorefloats\endcsname` (or `\makeatletter\efloat@restorefloats\makeatother`) right after `\processdelayedfloats` will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}

\processdelayedfloats
\csname efloat@restorefloats\endcsname

\section{Appendix}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table 2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Drawback: This uses an internal command of the `endfloat` package. But since it is there for a very long time (the oldest version I could find on the net is v2.4 from 1995) it is highly unlikely that it will go away in the future.